# Laravel update table with foreign key

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

So am working with two tables, campaign and task.

```
class Campaign extends Model {
    public function task()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Task');
    }
}
```

and model for task

```
class Task extends Model {
    public function campaign()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Campaign');
    }
}
```

so I am trying to update both tables using data from one form.
table campaign has a foreign key `campain_id` on Tasks.
This is my controller code TO UPDATE both tables but I am getting an error

```
public function update(Request $request, $TaskID)
    {

        $campaign = Campaign::Find($TaskID);
        $campaign-> campaign_name = $request->campaign_name;
        $campaign -> company = $request->company;

        $campaign->save();

        $stores= Task::where('campaign_id','=',$TaskID)->first();
        $store ->company = $request->input('company');
        $store->save();
    }
```

This is the error am getting and cannot really understand as am still new on Laravel.

```
in TaskController.php line 214
at HandleExceptions->handleError('2', 'Creating default object from empty value', 'F:\Projects\Dashboard\app\Http\Controllers\TaskController.php', '214', array('request' => object(Request), 'TaskID' => '5', 'campaign' => object(Campaign), 'stores' => object(Task), 'store' => object(stdClass))) in TaskController.php line 214
at TaskController->update(object(Request), '5')
```

please help identify my problem to have it working and update both tables at the same time

Comment: Which line is line 214?

Answer (score 0):

Which line is line 214?

You're saving the results to **$stores** variable, but you later reference it using **$store** variable which is empty, that's why you're getting the error.

Replace

```
$stores= Task::where('campaign_id','=',$TaskID)->first();
```

with

```
$store = Task::where('campaign_id','=',$TaskID)->first();
```

**NOTE:** You can avoid loading related tasks explicitely by using the relations you defined. In order to get all the tasks for a campaign you can simply access **$campaign->task** to get all related tasks.

Comment: though am still getting this error after the correction

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause' (SQL:

Comment: What is the SQL query? You should get it in the error message

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause' (SQL: update `tasks` set `send_at` = , `age_from` = , `age_to` = , `updated_at` = 2016-08-22 16:27:35 where `id` is null)

Comment: that is the sql error, i, thoght when updating a record the primary key just remains the same. and plus the where clause is referencing the foreign key from campaigns table

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause' (SQL: update tasks set send_at = , age_from = , age_to = , updated_at = 2016-08-22 16:27:35 where id is null) –

Comment: could you pliz help me sought this issue

Comment: Post your table structures, full code of your models and the code that causes the error